# Hide the mailing list address on the recipient details

Tags: mailgun

Is there a way in mailgun to hide the mailing list address on the recipient details when sending to a mailing list.

When you click the show details on the recipient, you will see the details below. How can I hide or remove the mailing list address.

[recipient details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYaux.png)

from:
to: 
date:
subject:
mailing list:
mailed-by:
signed-by:
unsubscribe:
security: